# GNU Octave's regexprep possibly numbers optional groups incorrectly

Tags: regex, octave

Backreferencing groups (parentheses) in a regular expression is done with `$1 $2 $3`, etc. in *GNU Octave* (4.2.2) and *MATLAB*.

But, in <s>both</s> *GNU Octave* <s>and *MATLAB*</s> optional groups are not numbered if not matched. Is this a bug?

Here is an example:

```
regexprep("abc","(a)(b)?(c)","$3,$2,$1")
ans = c,b,a
regexprep("ac","(a)(b)?(c)","$3,$2,$1")
ans = ,c,a
```

expected result of the second variant:

```
c,,a
```

here is something similar in `sed`:

```
echo -e "abc\nac" | sed -E 's/(a)(b)?(c)/\3,\2,\1/'
c,b,a
c,,a
```

When I look at the regexp, there are three sets of parentheses and the third one is clearly the one that is supposed to match c, so c should come first in the output. But, since the second one is not matched, c is upgraded to slot 2 in the backreferences.

I think that this is a bug, because the author of the regular expression cannot possibly know whether a string will contain the optional bit or not. Regardless, the author must decide beforehand what to substitute with what backreference.

It seems to me that *sed* gets it right and the numbering should adhere to the perceived parentheses in the regular expression, not how the groups end up matching.

A workaround I am using now is to use `*` quantifiers and `?` inside the group rather than making groups optional.

So:

```
regexprep("ac","(a)(b?)(c)","$3,$2,$1")
ans = c,,a
```

But, clearly, this is more complicated in more complex regular expressions, such as, matching a variable that possibly has an index:

```
(\w+([([]?\d*[])]?))
```

is supposed to match `lambda` and `lambda[1]`, but also catches `lamda[]` versus

```
(\w+([([]\d+[])])?)
```

which is what I really want, but this will mess up the backreferencing.

<s>I tested this really quickly in MATLAB and it seemed to be the same thing.</s> (edit: tested again later, MATLAB does it right)

Comment: In MATLAB you could use named tokens, which I think would look like this: `regexprep("abc","(<a>a)(<b>b)?(<c>c)","$<c>,$<b>,$<a>")`. However, it does not work in Octave, the Octave documentation does not mention these named tokens.

Comment: In Matlab (R2017b) the second variant, `regexprep('ac','(a)(b)?(c)','$3,$2,$1')`, gives `'c,,a'` as expected. Maybe it's an Octave bug. You could report it to Savannah

Comment: Named tokens would have been a neat workaround. Thanks!  ... regexp has them, but Octave's regexprep() seems to not support the $<name> reference (yet, hopefully).

Comment: It turns out that this is a known bug with `regexp()` in GNU Octave. [Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?38149). The named groups can be a workaround if I avoid using `regexprep()` altogether and instead call `regexp()` and then process the output. I can write this up as an answer or accept one of yours if you post something. But, in summary: you're both right, it seems. (Though I cannot check matlab behaviour at home, colleagues at work use it).

Answer (score 1):

It is a bug in *GNU Octave*, but not in *MATLAB*. The relevant Bug report is [Bug 38149 on Savannah](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?38149).

The root cause is that optional tokens are not included in regexp's "token" return value when the match is empty, so regexprep doesn't see them (if they are not matched) and cannot give them the right reference number.

### Workarounds

If the optional group is not actually needed in the replacement, it can be written as `(?:pattern)`, then the numbering becomes predictable again (independent of string to match). Let's say you want to do something like in the *variable name* example in the question text, then this will have reliable numbering

```
regexprep('a[12]^(0.5)',...
          '(\w+(?:[([]\d+[])])?)\^\(([+-]?[\d.]+)\)',...
          'power($1,$2)')
```

If you *do* need the optional group in the replacement pattern, then, as Cris Luengo mentioned, a named group could work. Here is example code that is meant to only cover the problems described here, it is *not* a replacement for regexprep:

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -q
function [SUB]=RE_workaround(in_string,pattern,substitution)
[N,ST,S]=regexp(in_string,pattern,"names","split","start");
if iscell(N)
  n=length(ST);
  SUB=cell(n,1);
  for i=1:n
    SUB{i}=substitute_match(N{i},ST{i},S{i},substitution);
  endfor
else
  SUB=substitute_match(N,ST,S,substitution);
endif
endfunction

function [SUB]=substitute_match(name,split,start,subpat)
  assert(~isempty(start) && isnumeric(start));
  nmatch=length(start);
  assert(length(split)==nmatch+1);
  fn=fieldnames(name);
  SUB=split{1};
  for j=1:nmatch
    substr=subpat;
    for k=1:length(fn)
      named_backreference=strcat('$',fn{k});
      rep=getfield(name,fn{k});
      substr=strrep(substr,named_backreference,rep{j});
    endfor
    SUB=cstrcat(SUB,substr,split{j+1});
  endfor
endfunction
```

This is meant as an illustration of how this might work, it's probably not a good idea to use the above code as is.